# How do I use a function inside of a while loop until I get my desired outcome?

Tags: python

```
import random
u = int(input("Enter the security parameter"))
half = int(u/2)


def Prime_Check(n):

    isprime = True
    for i in range(2,int(n/2)):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("is not prime")
            isprime = False
            break
    if isprime != False:
        print("number is likely prime")
        return n

while #p is not prime
    p = (random.getrandbits(half))
    Prime_Check(p)
```

I am trying to get the my while loop to continue until p is prime , but I'm not sure how I would do that with the function I created , do I need to do something like "return true" in my function and then "while function != true"? I'm confused how to implement this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to return `True` or `False` from your function, depending on whether `n` is prime or not. Then, use that as the condition of the `while` loop.

Comment: Side-note: Learn to use `//` appropriately. Every time your code includes `int(something/2)` you should really have used `something // 2` to properly use pure `int` floor division, instead of floating point true division which you then coerce back to `int`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger is that just like the floor value? that looks a lot cleaner ! Thank you have implemented your advice!

Comment: @01Cyber_cyber10: Yeah, `//` is defined to mean floor division (note: Unlike some other languages, it's actually *floor*, not *towards zero*, so `7 // 4` is `1`, but `-7 // 4` is `-2`; your math is all with non-negative numbers, so the distinction is irrelevant). When performed with `int`s, the result stays `int`, so there's no risk of math going awry due to floating point precision issues for the intermediate values.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's really handy to know , appreciate you taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options, but I would make your function return a boolean and then break out of the loop once the value is True. Meanwhile, make your while loop always True.

```
while True:
    p = (random.getrandbits(half))
    is_prime = Prime_Check(p)
    if is_prime:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return `True` or `False` from your function, depending on whether `n` is prime or not. Then, use that as the condition of the `while` loop.

```
def Prime_Check(n):
    isprime = True
    for i in range(2,int(n/2)):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("is not prime")
            return False
    print("number is likely prime")
    return True
```

Then,

```
more_loops = True
while more_loops:
    p = (random.getrandbits(half))
    more_loops = Prime_Check(p)
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense , I wasn't aware how to return true from a function . Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You would indeed need to make your function that checks if a number is prime to return a `bool` (i.e. `True` or `False`):

```py
import random
u = int(input("Enter the security parameter"))
half = int(u/2)
p = random.getrandbits(half)


def Prime_Check(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n/2)):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


while not Prime_Check(p):
    p = random.getrandbits(half)

print(f"Found a prime!: {p}")
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your Prime_check function will return None when the number is not prime (or the number itself if it is). The 'Truthy' value of that will be True if the number is prime and False if it is not which makes your function usable as a condition. So the only change you have to make is to take that result and use it to control the loop.  Start with a non-prime to make the loop go at least once

```
p = 4 # (non-prime) 
while not Prime_Check(p)
    p = (random.getrandbits(half))
```

*I would have used 1 as the initial non-prime, but your function thinks that 1 is prime*

Comment: interesting take , and your completely right my function does identify 1 as prime , starting the for loop at 2 was my work around as I couldn't figure out how to exclude it! Thank you for the wisdom.